# How do I change to a pointer when I hover over a custom lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I recently created my first custom Lightning component that will open up a link when you hover over an image. It works fine, but how do I get the arrow to turn into a pointer when I hover over the image so the user knows it is clickable? I think this needs to be done inside the controller with JavaScript. I tried using CSS in the controller and it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
Component:

<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="width:70%;" onclick="{! c.openPowerBI }">   
        <img src="{!$Resource.PowerBILogo}" class="pointer"/>
    </div
</aura:component>>

Controller:

({    
    openPowerBI : function(component, event, helper) {
         window.open("https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/"); 
      }  
    
})
```

Comment: You neglected to include the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the easiest way to get the pointer is to use a link:

```
<a class="slds-align_absolute-center" href="#" style="width:70%;" onclick="{! c.openPowerBI }">   
  <img src="{!$Resource.PowerBILogo}" />
</div
```

---

```
openPowerBI : function(component, event, helper) {
  window.open("https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/"); 
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

---

The CSS should also work:

```
.THIS .pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Note that Aura is a bit tricky with the CSS, you need to learn when to use a space after .THIS (or not).

Namely, if the element is directly descended from aura:component, you do not use a space, but if it has any parent elements, then you do.

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work for me. I am not sure if it is because the controller has javascript in it, or whether I am not inserting it in the right way. It is giving me this error: Failed to save openPowerBIController.js: c.openPowerBI: Failed to parse CONTROLLER for js://c.openPowerBI: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Expected ':' [5, 11]: '.pointer': Source

Comment: @MarkV You need to do that in the STYLES section, not the CONTROLLER.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I am very new to this. I wasn't even aware there was a separate styles section. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @MarkV you're welcome!